# Measuring the sections of a 9-patch programatically

Tags: android, nine-patch

Is there an Android API or other way that I can use to find out how tall a 9-patch's content region is? I've got dynamically stylable content on my app and need to make sure that the font size is never too big for the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I dont understand you.. but one of the purposes of the 9-patch is to expand dinamically to the content. so if you create a well formed 9 patch using the tool from android sdk folders, it doesn't matters how big is the font size, the button will expand to it. Also you can set a max height of the buttons in case you need it.

Comment: The issue is that the button's height and font size are both set dynamically using dip instead of fill_parent or wrap_content. If (for example) the user sets the button size to be 75x75 but the font size to 30 the text will wrap and/or gets cut off at the bottom depending on the 9patch and the label. I'd like to be able to calculate the largest possible size for the button's text and cap the user-provided value so that doesn't happen.